# Multiple or conditions within if statements

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

I had a basic doubt in evaluation of or conditions within  a single if statement.Suppose l and r are pointers to Tree Nodes,in a scenario where either of the pointers becomes null,the check line is evaluated and false is returned. What i want to know is as either of l or r becomes null,shouldn't a null pointer exception be also raised for the third condition in the same if statement? If I place the third condition as first one an exception is raised.Can someone highlight how both the statements(second statement is mentioned as a comment) are evaluated in each case?

```
bool isSymmetric(TreeNode* root) {
    queue<TreeNode*>q;
    if (root == NULL)
        return true;
    q.push(root->left);
    q.push(root->right);
    TreeNode *l, *r;
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        l = q.front();
        q.pop();
        r = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (l == NULL && r == NULL)
            continue;
        if (l == NULL || r == NULL || l->val != r->val) return false; //check
        //  if (l->val != r->val || l == NULL || r == NULL)
        q.push(l->left);
        q.push(r->right);
        q.push(l->right);
        q.push(r->left);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There are no null-pointer exceptions in C++. If you dereference a null pointer, the program is allowed to do whatever.

Comment: Dereferencing an invalid pointer (like for example a null pointer) then that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite cute really. (I'm replacing the pre-C++11 `NULL` with `nullptr`.)

`continue` will be called if `l` *and* `r` are both `nullptr`.

And because `||` is short-circuited, `l->val != r->val` will only be evaluated if `l` is not `nullptr` *and* `r` is not `nullptr`.

You need to get used to idioms like this in C++ as part of your becoming fluent in the language.

Note that the behaviour on *dereferencing* `nullptr` is *undefined* in C++; an exception is not necessarily thrown. Don't talk about null pointer exceptions when talking about standard C++.

Finally, can you change the function to take a `const TreeNode* root`?

Comment: So if one of the previous conditions is satisfied,the whole if isn't evaluated it seems?

Comment: That is correct. Both && and || have this property, unless overloaded.